# Behat mink - can't test rest methods without know identifier

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I had an issue to test some rest api: I can't get id from created resource to check if that resource exists. Here I'm checking id: dab2b33f-0a36-4cd6-a0d4-c175515abbab but every time I run the "Scenario: Add new city" I had different identifier.

```
  Scenario: Add new city
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "POST" request to "/cities" with body:
    """
    {
      "name": "City1",
      "geo": {
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0
      }
    }
    """
    Then the response status code should be 201
    And the response should be in JSON
    And the header "Content-Type" should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8"

  Scenario: Delete city with existing id
    When I add "Content-Type" header equal to "application/json"
    And I add "Accept" header equal to "application/json"
    And I send a "DELETE" request to "/cities/dab2b33f-0a36-4cd6-a0d4-c175515abbab"
    Then the response status code should be 204
```

Have anybody idea how to get id from last response and operate on second scenario on it?

Answer (score 1):

The scenarios are and should be independent, I don't think you can use a value from the first scenario in the second scenario unless you define your own step(s) and save the value independently maybe in a data class using static variables/methods and read it in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I inspired by https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/features/main/uuid.feature, enabled to set identifier for my API.
So it looks like:
1) I have doctrine data fixutres where I add some record with hardcoded identfier to manage dependencies needed in tests
2) I use those identifiers in my tests
3) I create some resource with IDENTIFIER